# Adding and Using Resources in a Windows Driver

Tags: windows, driver, resources, 32-bit

Is it possible for a windows driver to have resources? If so how could I add them and more importantly access them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am adding only version information resources to drivers. Simply add rc-file to your sources.

```
SOURCES = ver.rc \
          main.cpp
```

If you want to access resources from your driver I can suggest to get the driver base address and use IMAGE_DOS_HEADER/IMAGE_NT_HEADERS/DataDirectory to find the resources.